# Resize view right-to-left with animation on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview

I would like to resize UIView from right side to left (opposite).
Now I have view with rect like this: `CGRectMake(100.f, 0.f, 100.f, 100.f)`;

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
  view.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 200.f, 100.f);
}];
```

The problem is that animation is not nice. It bounces to the right (gets bigger) and than moves to location 0.0,0.0.

I would like to achieve the same effect like when resizing from left to right.

**EDIT: code**

```
- (void)resizeSearchBar:(int)type
{
    //resize - bigger
    if (type == 1) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 280.f, 44.f);
        }];
    }
    //resize - smaller
    else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(95.f, 0.f, 185.f, 44.f);
        }];
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I've also tried to change View properties in IB like that:
[image]

Still no luck...

Comment: Can you show window creation code and from which method did you start this animation? Actually, it looks like you trying to animate wrong "property"...

Comment: Actually I want to resize UISearchBar. It is created from nib and connected to a property self.mySearchBar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it to work with the hint from this answer: [Can't animate the frame or bounds of a UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636367/cant-animate-the-frame-or-bounds-of-a-uisearchbar/10319005#10319005)

The trick is to call `[searchBar layoutSubviews];` in your animation block after setting the frame.

Here is what I got to work in my sample:

```
- (IBAction)resizeButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    //resize - bigger
    if (searchBar.frame.origin.x == 95) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 280.f, 44.f);
            [searchBar layoutSubviews];
        }];
    }
    //resize - smaller
    else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(95.f, 0.f, 185.f, 44.f);
            [searchBar layoutSubviews];
        }];
    }

}
```

Comment: This was the clue I needed to solve a choppy/popping animation problem -- thanks! But instead of `layoutSubviews` I called `layoutIfNeeded`, in exactly the same place as you have it, and the animation then ran as desired. I note the substitution because, per class ref, you should not call `layoutSubviews` directly.

Answer (score 0):

It bounces because the duration is much less!!

Increase the duration ..and i think it will make it more clear how it animates

K try this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                  delay:0.0 
                options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
             animations:^ {

     self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 280.f, 44.f);
             } 
             completion:^(BOOL finished) {

             }];
```

[Chk here for Options](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions)

Comment: @BorutTomazin Try This  :) Hope it helps..For more look into block animations

Answer (score 0):

I think this is useful to you just see bellow demo link...

https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController?_tmc=UFw1P_Ai9brJd4WEpSlPbNrXBWOvsYZ6gNPi_derQik

i hope this help you..
:)

edited...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:4.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                     animations:nil
                     completion:^{
                         view.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 200.f, 100.f);}];
```

not sure but try this and also use different Animation like "UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve",etc....
hope this help you....

Comment: That's good example but not for my problem. I am not just moving view left/right, but also resizing it...