# UIBarButtonItems' customView doesn't animate with resizing

Tags: ios, animation, resize, navigationitem

I'm trying to add a simple animation when I resize the UISearchBar from the leftBarButtonItem.
For some reason, the resize doesn't animate, although the searchBar's size is modified. However, if I try to modify the searchBar's alpha it does animate.

Here is the code

```
UISearchBar *baseSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:baseSearchBar];
```

And the animation method is:

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
    searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 40);
    searchBar.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {  
}];
```

As i said, the resize DOES work, but not animated and the animation works if I'm trying to change the alpha.

One more thing... I tried to do the same thing for the rightBarButtonItem and the animation worked..

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(expandWithAnimation:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40);
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate [Can't animate the frame or bounds of a UISearchBar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10319005/440060)

Comment: Thank you! I found the answer on that link. All I needed to do was [searchBar layoutSubviews];

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't animate the frame or bounds of a UISearchBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636367/cant-animate-the-frame-or-bounds-of-a-uisearchbar)